# Type mismatch vba 2d array

Tags: vba, excel

```
strData = "{""INTEREST EARNING ASSETS"", """";" & _
        """Interbank Placement"", ""goku"";" & _
        """Corporate Bonds"", ""goku"";" & _
        """Government Bonds and T-Bills"", ""goku"";" & _
        """Customer Loans"", ""cow"";" & _
        """"", ""soccer"";" & _
        """Customer Loans"", ""cow"";" & _
        """Customer Loans"", ""cow"";" & _
        """test"", 444444;" & _
        """drinks"", ""goal""}"

    varData = Evaluate(strData)

    For intCounter1 = 1 To UBound(varData, 1)
        For intCounter2 = 1 To UBound(varData, 2)
            ActiveCell.Value = varData(intCounter1, intCounter2)
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Next intCounter2
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next intCounter1
```

The above code works and it prints 2 columns of the given value. For example

```
INTEREST EARNING ASSETS *BLANK*
Interbank Placement      goku 
Corporate bonds          goku
```

and so on

However, when I add an extra line on the 3rd line in the strData like below, it says type mismatch. I really don't understand why? As a matter of fact, if I add an extra line to any lines below, it gives me the same error. Why is this happening?

```
strData = "{""INTEREST EARNING ASSETS"", """";" & _
            """Interbank Placement"", ""goku"";" & _
            """Interbank Placement"", ""goku"";" & _
            """Corporate Bonds"", ""goku"";" & _
            """Government Bonds and T-Bills"", ""goku"";" & _
            """Customer Loans"", ""cow"";" & _
            """"", ""soccer"";" & _
            """Customer Loans"", ""cow"";" & _
            """Customer Loans"", ""cow"";" & _
            """test"", 444444;" & _
            """drinks"", ""goal""}"
```

Comment: There's a 255 character limit on Evaluate

Comment: Is there any way I can get around this to add more values to my 2D array? Thanks

Comment: You can user shorter values.  Alternatively, explain why you're doing this at all: it doesn't seem like a useful approach.  It would be easier to construct your array in the regular way, or maybe pull it from a worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Use direct value assignment of table/array using `Range().Resize(n,m).Value =`

```
Dim varData() as Variant
ReDim varData(1 to 4, 1 to 2)

varData(1,1) = "INTEREST EARNING ASSETS"
varData(1,2) = "*BLANK*"
varData(2,1) = "Interbank Placement"
varData(2,2) = 1.2344#
varData(3,1) = "Corporate bonds"
varData(3,2) = 1.04305#
varData(4,1) = "Customer Loans"
varData(4,2) = 1.10383#

ActiveCell.Resize(4,2).Value = varData
```

PS. There is never a need to use the select statement to assign values. Just pick the right cell reference and use it directly to read/write values.